# "Content" property / XAML

Tags: xaml

I'm trying the use WinUI 3 Gallery but I experiencing this error most of the code.

`The property 'Default' is set more than once.`

I tried StackLayout but this time it gives this.

`An unexpected file break has occurred. The following items are not closed: Window. Line 24, position 17.`

I expecting:
No error.

Comment: Maybe you can paste the XAML ? Hard to tell you which element isn't closed without the code.

Answer (score 0):

1. This error An unexpected file break has occurred. The following items are not closed: Window. Line 24, position 17.
   Means that your XAML file is missing a  at the end
2. You mention using a StackLayout, you likely mean StackPanel and if you are using a StackLayout, it is not going to do what you think it will do